# Logback: send email via AWS SNS on error

Tags: java, logback, amazon-sns

I am using logback in our java application for logging. 
I want to send emails via AWS SNS whenever I encounter an error in my logs.
How can I do it for SNS?
Do I have to write a custom appender for it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you will have to write a custom appender.

And also make sure that the email id to whom you want to send the email to, should first subscribe to the SNS topic. With SNS you cannot send emails to arbitrary email IDs that are not subscribed to the topic